# How to set caret to a specific address in binary file opened with UltraEdit (UE) in hex edit mode?

Tags: binary, ultraedit

I have a large binary file about 2 GB. I open it with **UltraEdit** in **Hex Edit** mode, and try to drag the vertical scroll bar to set caret to a specific address like `0x12345678` or some other address. But when I drag a little, the address moves a lot! The larger the file, the harder to navigate to an address.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking in menu **Search** on menu item **Goto** or pressing <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> opens for a file currently displayed in hex editing mode the **Hex Goto** dialog.

In this dialog the byte offset to jump to can be entered in decimal or in hexadecimal when entered string starts with **0x** as in your example.

On first **Goto** you have to wait some seconds as UltraEdit (v22.10) parses the entire file for line terminators for line number indication although that should not be done for a binary file opened in hex edit mode as there are no line numbers displayed in hex edit mode. I have reported this issue already to IDM Computer Solutions, Inc., but this bug is not fixed up to now. Further **Goto** executions are much faster as no useless parsing for line terminators anymore.